# Ansible; How do you sort a list of integers

Tags: ansible

Ansible; How do you sort a list of integers
If suppose we have a list of integers like

```
vars:
  numberlist: {3,7,1,6,2,7,4,9}
```

Is there a function to sort this?

Comment: The braces `{}` are used to declare dictionaries. Use brackets `[]` to declare lists.

Answer (score 5):

Use the filter [*sort*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.sort). For example,

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ numberlist|sort }}"
  vars:
    numberlist: [3,7,1,6,2,7,4,9]
```

gives

```
  msg:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
  - 6
  - 7
  - 7
  - 9
```